# ESLint warns React Query mutation must be included in dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, use-effect, react-query

I am using `react-query` library and I get `ESLint useEffect dependency` warning.
my code is something like this:

```
const postProductMutation = useMutation(...);

useEffect(() => {
    postProductMutation.mutateAsync()
}, [])
```

now, as `ESLint` says, I should put `postProductMutation` in dependency array. but if I do, I will create an infinite loop.
any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should destruct the value returned from `useMutation` and include that in dependency array.

```
  const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(...);

  useEffect(() => {
    mutateAsync();
  }, [mutateAsync]);
```